# GetFeatureInfo doesn't work!

Tags: openlayers-2, wms, mapserver, getfeatureinfo

I'm new at openlayers and I am having some trouble when trying to display the feature info.

I have the map working, with the layers I want to add in, but it seems that when I try to ask for the info just like in the following example:

http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/getfeatureinfo-popup.html

It shows an error:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'addControl' of undefined

As I said, my map is working perfectly and I am not able to figure out why it shows this error, can someone help me on this?!

Here goes the piece of code that is anoying me:

```
    var info = new OpenLayers.Control.WMSGetFeatureInfo({
        url: 'http://localhost/cgi-bin/mapserv.exe      map=/ms4w/apache/htdocs/lixo.map&layers=Edificos', 
        title: 'Identify features by clicking',
        queryVisible: true,
        eventListeners: {
            getfeatureinfo: function(event) {
                map.addPopup(new OpenLayers.Popup.FramedCloud(
                    "chicken", 
                    map.getLonLatFromPixel(event.xy),
                    null,
                    event.text,
                    null,
                    true
                ));
            }
        }
    });
    map.addControl(info);
    info.activate();
```

Thak you very much!

UPDATE_***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__**

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml">
          <head>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0">
            <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
            <title>Faculdade de Ciências da Universidade de Lisboa</title>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="utilitarios.css" type="text/css">

            </style>


            <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3.2&sensor=false"></script>
            <script src="http://openlayers.org/api/OpenLayers.js"></script>
            <script defer="defer" type="text/javascript">

            OpenLayers.ProxyHost = "proxy.cgi?url=";

             var map, info;
             OpenLayers.IMAGE_RELOAD_ATTEMPTS = 3;
             OpenLayers.Util.onImageLoadErrorColor = "transparent";


               function init(){

                  var navigation_control = new OpenLayers.Control.Navigation({});

        //DEFINIÇÃO DOS COMANDOS A UTILIZAR NO MAPA
                  var controls_array = [
                  navigation_control,
                  new OpenLayers.Control.PanZoomBar({}),
                  new OpenLayers.Control.LayerSwitcher({}),
                  new OpenLayers.Control.Permalink({}),
                  new OpenLayers.Control.MousePosition({}),
                  ];

        //CRIAÇÃO DA VARIÁVEL MAPA COM PROJECÇÃO E LIMITES ASSOCIADOS.
                  map = new OpenLayers.Map( 'mapa',{
                 controls: controls_array,
                  projection: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:900913"),
                  displayProjection: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:3763"),
                  numZoomLevels: 18,
                   maxResolution: 156543.0339,
                   maxExtent: new OpenLayers.Bounds(-1019723.067567,  4686569.677227,-1018877.96253, 4687126.173453),
                   // maxExtent: new OpenLayers.Bounds(-1021183.067567, 4686569.677227, -1017159.96253, 4687181.173453)
                   units: "m"
                 } );


        // DEFINIÇÃO DE LAYERS DE INFORMAÇÃO

                  var caminhos = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS( 
                  'Caminhos',
                  "http://localhost/cgi-bin/mapserv.exe?map=/ms4w/apache/htdocs/lixo.map&layers=Caminhos",
                  {layers: 'basic','transparent': true, 'isBaseLayer': false});
                  //{'opacity': 0.5, 'isBaseLayer': true, 'visibility': true}  );

                  var escadas = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS(
                  "Escadas",
                  "http://localhost/cgi-bin/mapserv.exe?map=/ms4w/apache/htdocs/lixo.map&layers=Escadas",
                   {'layers': 'basic','transparent': true }
                   );


        // LAYERS DE API's EXTERIORES

                  var aerial = new OpenLayers.Layer.Bing({
                   type: "Aerial",
                   key: "AkDvQXEdeliH2C-JNTFWx_lnoUyIlfbRhdZoucaBHWBvHGIxmF_etkgXGYr0CzXE",
                   sphericalMercator: true
                    });

                    // Bing's Road imagerySet
                    var road = new OpenLayers.Layer.Bing({
                     key: "AkDvQXEdeliH2C-JNTFWx_lnoUyIlfbRhdZoucaBHWBvHGIxmF_etkgXGYr0CzXE",
                     sphericalMercator: true,
                    type: "Road"});

                 // Bing's AerialWithLabels imagerySet
                    var hybrid = new OpenLayers.Layer.Bing({
                   key: "AkDvQXEdeliH2C-JNTFWx_lnoUyIlfbRhdZoucaBHWBvHGIxmF_etkgXGYr0CzXE",
                    type: "AerialWithLabels",
                    sphericalMercator: true,
                    name: "Bing Aerial With Labels"
                    });

                    var osmLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM("OpenStreetMap");


        //ADIÇÂO DE LAYERS E DETERMINAÇAO DE ORDEM DE APRESENTAÇÂO

                   map.addLayers([road, aerial, hybrid, osmLayer]);
                  //map.addLayers([hybrid, edificios]);

                  map.addLayer(caminhos);
                  map.setLayerIndex(caminhos, 1); //set the image overlay to the bottom

                  map.addLayer(escadas);
                  map.setLayerIndex(escadas, 2);


        // ADIÇÂO DE CONTROLOS AO MAPA
                  map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.LayerSwitcher({title: 'Switch/add/remove layers'}));
                  map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.ScaleLine({}));
                  //map.zoomToMaxExtent();



        // TENTATIVA - ATRIBUTOS
                  var info = new OpenLayers.Control.WMSGetFeatureInfo({
                    url: 'http://localhost/cgi-bin/mapserv.exe?', 
                    title: 'Identify features by clicking',
                    queryVisible: true,
                    eventListeners: {
                        getfeatureinfo: function(event) {
                            map.addPopup(new OpenLayers.Popup.FramedCloud(
                                "chicken", 
                                map.getLocalXY(event.xy),
                                null,
                                event.text,
                                null,
                                true
                            ));
                        }
                    }
                });
                map.addControl(info);
                info.activate();


                 var selectCtrl = new OpenLayers.Control.SelectFeature(edificios, {
                    clickout: true, 
                    onSelect: open_infowin, 
                    //onUnselect: close_infowin
                  });

                 function open_infowin(event) {

                  var mousePos = this.events.getMousePosition(event);

                   infowin = new OpenLayers.Popup.FramedCloud(
                             "popup",
                             map.getLonLatFromViewPortPx(mousePos),
                             new OpenLayers.Size(300,150),
                             "Updating<br/>information...",
                             null,
                             true,
                             null
                           );
                map.addPopup(infowin);
            }

            */

                    var infoControls = {
                    click: new OpenLayers.Control.WMSGetFeatureInfo({
                        url: 'http://demo.opengeo.org/geoserver/wms', 
                        title: 'Identify features by clicking',
                        layers: [salas],
                        queryVisible: true
                    })}

        // CENTRAGEM DO MAPA
                var point=(-1019294, 4686862);
                  map.setCenter(point, 17);

                  }

                var count=0;


            </script>
         </head>
```

Here's a fuller version of the script. it doesn't include all the layers or the body part, but it would be too long, and I beilieve that's not ther source of the problem. I'm using MAPSERVER, can it be a configuration issue?! if so I attached my mapfile:

```
        MAP
          NAME "QGIS-MAP"
          # Map image size
          SIZE 1000 800
          UNITS meters
          QUERYMAP
                 STATUS ON
          END

        EXTENT -89279.355471 -100905.485742 -88614.316404 -100538.256445
          FONTSET './fonts/fonts.txt'
          SYMBOLSET './symbols/symbols.txt'
         PROJECTION
                "init=epsg:3763"
            END #end projection

          # Background color for the map canvas -- change as desired
          IMAGECOLOR 255 255 255
          Transparent true
          IMAGEQUALITY 95
          IMAGETYPE png



          SCALEBAR
            IMAGECOLOR 255 255 255
            LABEL
              COLOR 0 0 0
              SIZE TINY
            END
            STYLE 1
            SIZE 100 2
            COLOR 0 0 0
            UNITS MILES
            INTERVALS 2
            TRANSPARENT FALSE
            STATUS ON
          END 

          # Legend
          LEGEND
              IMAGECOLOR 255 255 255
            STATUS ON
            KEYSIZE 18 12
            LABEL
              TYPE BITMAP
              SIZE MEDIUM
              COLOR 0 0 89
            END
          END

           WEB
            TEMPLATE temp.html
            IMAGEPATH '/ms4w/tmp/ms_tmp/'
            IMAGEURL '/ms_tmp/'
            METADATA
              'ows_title'           'fcul'
              'ows_onlineresource'  'http://localhost/cgi-bin/mapserv.exe?'
              'ows_srs'             'EPSG:3763 EPSG:900913'
              "ows_enable_request"   "*"
              "ows_include_items" "all"
              "wms_include_items" "all"
            END

          END

        LAYER
            NAME 'Caminhos'
            TYPE POLYGON
            CONNECTIONTYPE postgis
            CONNECTION "dbname='fcul' host=localhost port=5432 user='postgres' password='****'"
            DATA 'geom FROM "campus"."exteriorcaminhos" USING UNIQUE gid USING srid=3763'
            METADATA
              'ows_title' 'Caminhos'
              "ows_include_items" "all"
              "wms_include_items" "all"
            END
            STATUS ON
           PROJECTION
                "init=epsg:3763"
            END #end projection
            CLASS
               NAME 'Caminhos' 
               STYLE
                 WIDTH 0.05 
                 OUTLINECOLOR 115 63 44
                 COLOR 249 239 189
               END
            END
          END

          LAYER
            NAME 'Escadas'
            TYPE POLYGON
            CONNECTIONTYPE postgis
            CONNECTION "dbname='fcul' host=localhost port=5432 user='postgres' password='****'"
            DATA 'geom FROM "campus"."edificiosescadas" USING UNIQUE gid USING srid=3763'
            METADATA
              'ows_title' 'Escadas'
            END
            STATUS ON
            TRANSPARENCY 50
            PROJECTION
                "init=epsg:3763"
            END #end projection
            CLASS
               NAME 'Escadas' 
               STYLE
                 WIDTH 0.91 
                 OUTLINECOLOR 235 116 255
                 COLOR 235 116 255
               END
            END
          END


        END
```

Comment: Guys, it seems like the problem vas in the order od the elments, it is not giving that error anymore. But it doesn't seem to show the popup aswell, any idea?!

Comment: What error if any do you see in firebug? Are you seeing any request being sent?

Comment: Post your entire code. You aren't initializing `map` as the right name or at the right time.

Comment: Devdatta, there are no errors in firebug. I attached the file bellow:

Comment: i've updated the question to include the rest of the code! thank you once again!

Comment: I beliee there is no request being sent when I clik, how can I check that?

Comment: @Alexandra To check if a request is being sent or received, you can use fiddler

Answer (score 1):

In your entire code is used `map.getLocalXY` instead of `map.getLonLatFromPixel`, this would cause an error and would not show the popup.

(Note: you adds two `OpenLayers.Control.LayerSwitcher` to the map)

Answer (score 0):

I have been going thru this and it seems like the code wasn't really the issue here.. It was my browser's configuration that wasn't allowing the request to be made.. I have asked for a friend's help and he's changed the configuration to allow it. I am not shure of what the problem was, but it has something to do with this:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10143093/origin-is-not-allowed-by-access-control-allow-origin

hopefully you'll have an informatic background and will be able to deciphre it.. (or if someone who understands the issue see this post, please feel free to explain) !

Thank you all =)